# How to render a hidden input control in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

In MVC3, there is a `HiddenInput` under `System.Web.Mvc`. But the in Mvc4, this attribute no longer exists.

Therefore, there is no way to write the annotation in the MVC3 way:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public int SubmittedByUserId { get; set; }
```

Can anyone tell me how to render a hidden input using data annotation in the view model in MVC4?

Comment: HiddenInput still exists in MVC 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.hiddeninputattribute.aspx Make sure you have the right using statements and are referencing the correct version of System.Web.Mvc

Comment: It works just fine for me, Do you get any message errors when you compile? Did you check if you are referencing all the libraries for mvc?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include **"System.Web.Mvc"** namespace before you start using it.